# How to insert Google Calendar event without a reminder

Tags: android, calendar

Is it possible to have an event without a reminder pop-up? Below is my Xamarin code to create an event (this question is not Xamarin specific, Java code would be almost the same):

```
  private static ContentValues BuildContentValues(int y, int m, int d, int h, int u, string text)
  {
     var now = new DateTime(y, m, d, h, u, 0);
     ContentValues eventValues = new ContentValues();
     eventValues.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.CalendarId, calendarId);


     eventValues.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Title, shorter);
     eventValues.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Description, text);
     eventValues.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Dtstart, GetDateTimeMS(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day, now.Hour, now.Minute));
     eventValues.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Dtend, GetDateTimeMS(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day, now.Hour, now.Minute));
     eventValues.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.HasAlarm, 0); // no affect
     eventValues.Put(CalendarContract.Reminders.InterfaceConsts.Minutes, 5);
     // eventValues.Put(CalendarContract.Reminders.InterfaceConsts.Method, 0); // crashes

     eventValues.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.EventTimezone, "UTC");
     eventValues.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.EventEndTimezone, "UTC");

     return eventValues;
  }
```

Have not had any luck googling an answer to this.

Answer (score 0):

A [Reminder](https://developers.google.com/calendar/concepts/reminders#reminders) consists of:

- When to show the reminder, expressed as minutes before the event start time.
- The delivery method to use.

Reminders can be specified for whole calendars and for individual events. Users can set default reminders for each of their calendars; these defaults apply to all events within that calendar. However, users can also override these defaults for individual events, replacing them with a different set of reminders.

---

[Overriding default reminders](https://developers.google.com/calendar/concepts/reminders#overriding_default_reminders)

To override the default reminders when you insert or modify an event, set **reminders.useDefault to false** and populate reminders.overrides with the new reminder set.

---

In your case, you can disable your calendar's default reminder (if there is an existing reminder configured) by setting **reminders.useDefault to false**, no need to populate the reminders.overrides methods and minutes.

**Sample No Reminder Event:**

```
{
  "end": {
    "dateTime": "2020-11-27T03:53:00+08:00"
  },
  "start": {
    "dateTime": "2020-11-27T03:43:00+08:00"
  },
  "summary": "Test Event No Reminder",
  "reminders": {
    "useDefault": false
  }
}
```

[image]

---

> 

---

**Sample Default Reminder Event:**

```
{
  "end": {
    "dateTime": "2020-11-27T03:53:00+08:00"
  },
  "start": {
    "dateTime": "2020-11-27T03:43:00+08:00"
  },
  "summary": "Test Event Default Reminder"
}
```

[image]

---

> 

---

Reference:

https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events#reminders.useDefault